# Extract month from timestamp of a dict using python

Tags: python, dictionary, datetime

```
Data - {
  "36": "Tue, 31 Jan 2023 16:00:00 GMT", 
  "240": "Wed, 30 Nov 2022 16:00:00 GMT", 
  "284": "Sat, 31 Dec 2022 16:00:00 GMT", 
  "1012": "Mon, 31 Oct 2022 16:00:00 GMT", 
  "2170": "Wed, 31 Aug 2022 16:00:00 GMT", 
  "7512": "Fri, 30 Sep 2022 16:00:00 GMT"
}
```

I have tried using :

```
 for m in dict.values:
    m = m.dt.month
```

Required output -

```
{"Jan 2023" : "36", "Nov 2022" : "240", "Dec 2022" : "284", "Oct 2022" : "1012", "Aug 2022" : "2170", "Sep 2022" : "7512"}
```

Comment: You need to convert the str in one format to datetime and then back in different format

Comment: What if there are multiple values for the same month?

Comment: There wont be multiple values of the same month because it is a count database.

Comment: try: `res={f"{month} {year}": key for key,value in dic.items() for month, year in [value.split()[2:4]]}`

Comment: @YashMehta, there is way more pythonic way to deal with that - look at the duplicate link

Comment: @prj, if this comes from DB, why not handle this in the query? Maybe XY problem

Comment: you can also try: `res={f"{datetime.strptime(value, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z').strftime('%b %Y')}": key for key, value in dic.items()}` using `datetime` function